# Система бронирования Bookeo оставить Webhook

Tags: php, python

Есть система бронирования Bookeo. У него есть свой апи и Вебхуки. Нужно поставить вебхук, но не понятно как. Кто может делал?

Comment: Полный список возможных значений для домена и типа webhook приведен в справочнике по API для метода POST / webhooks: http://www.bookeo.com/apiref/index.html#!/Webhooks/webhooks_post

Comment: Вот эту доку я не могу понять )